# Updating rational team concert workitem with git commitid

Tags: git, gitlab, rtc

We are using gitlab as our git scm. Also we use rational team concert as ALM app.

I would like to link rational team concert workitem and git commit id when a user push code changes to gitlab either from ecplise or from visual studio to generate traceblity between work item and commit id.

I know this is possible with github or with gitweb comes along with git client.

How can I do this with gitlab?

Is there a gitlab web hook available which will create related work item link between rational team concert work item and gitlab commit id?